# unique() but only on consecutive rows

Tags: r

I am looking for equivalent of `unique()`, but done only on the consecutive rows. I.e., in the following example:

```
df <- data.frame(a = rep(c(1:3,1:3), each = 3), b = rep(c(4:6,4:6), each = 3))
unique(df)
#  a b
#1 1 4
#4 2 5
#7 3 6
```

I want to actually get:

```
function_I_am_looking_for(df)
#   a b
#1  1 4
#4  2 5
#7  3 6
#10 1 4
#13 2 5
#16 3 6
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `rleid` to create a grouping variable and `slice` the first row

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
df %>% 
   group_by(grp = rleid(a, b)) %>%
   slice(1) %>%
   ungroup %>%
   select(-grp)
# A tibble: 6 x 2
#      a     b
#  <int> <int>
#1     1     4
#2     2     5
#3     3     6
#4     1     4
#5     2     5
#6     3     6
```

---

Or the same with `data.table` syntax, grouped by `rleid` of 'a', b', extract the first elements row index (`.I`) and subset the rows with that

```
setDT(df)[df[, .I[1], .(rleid(a, b))]$V1]
```

Or using `unique` with `by`

```
unique(setDT(df)[, grp := rleid(a, b)], by = "grp")
```

Or, **OP prefered version**, solution for general `data.frame` using just a base functionality:

```
unique(cbind(rleidv(df), df))[,-1]
```

Comment: Thanks for inspiration! :-) I modified it and included the solution in your answer :-)